# ServiceNow: Manipulate DOM of ootb Widget

Tags: css, angularjs, dom, servicenow

Our team is working in ServiceNow and trying to make some aesthetic changes to the ootb Form widget.  We've cloned that widget and are trying to give the Form Sections a different background and some larger/bolder font.  Since the Form layout is buried in some template code in the system, the only way for us to change the look and feel is to manipulate the DOM in our cloned widget.  We've read that the best way to do this is to use the Link Function tab, but we are unsure how to begin.  After inspecting our console, it looks like we want to manipulate the parent div of a  tag.  What is the syntax so that we can target that specific div?

We've tried different variations of this without any success:

```
angular.element('legend').parent().addClass('newDiv');
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how big changes you want to make are, I would just try and add CSS using the page CSS. I don't know how familiar you are with ServiceNow, but if you ctrl + right-click the widget in the portal, click 'Page in designer', and then the 'Page' button with a gear on it in the top right corner, then you can add page specific CSS there. I've used this a lot, and it also saves you from cloning the widget.

Comment: Thanks @Astrid!  Yes, that would normally work, but the issue is we want to add css to a div that precedes a <legend> tag, both of which do not have any ootb class associated with them.  If we could do this in pure css, that would be ideal, but not sure if that can be done...

Comment: I know what you mean. I would give it a try, though, and just select super specifically. I've been using this one a lot: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp .
Either way, good luck.